# How to limit the amount of spillover to other CPUs from a single process

Tags: performance, cpu-usage, multithreading

Please excuse the complete ignorance of my question - I'm probably lacking the right terminology here...

I am trying to understand how a single process (R session) can spill over to all CPUs on our server (n=72). It seems to happen when the memory required for a given object or operation surpasses a given threshold.

This behavior can be seen in the following screenshot from `htop`, showing that all CPUs are being utilized:

[image]

During this point in time, both "marc" and "ismael" were running a single session on R, as can be seen from the output of `top`:

[image]

Ismael's process has exceeded some limit that results in multi-threading, where >5000% of CPU is being used. While this behavior might be desired for large calculations, I get the feeling that it is making a lot of things slow down on the entire server. It's not even that clear to me from occasions where this has happened to me that this multi-threading is improving the speed of the calculation.

Can someone please explain to me what is going on, and if there are any settings that we might adjust in order to improve the performance of job distributions on the server?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried asking ismael to limit how many CPU cores his R jobs use?   sometimes it's both easy and effective to set guidelines on excessive use of a shared resource.   BTW, are these jobs run directly by the user, or via a batch scheduling/resource-management system like `slurm` or `torque`?

Comment: @cas - I have had the same behavior happen to me; where, while running a single R job, the processing spills over to many CPUs. As I mentioned, this is dependent upon the size of the job within a single R session. Yes, the jobs are run by a single user - calling `R` in the console opens the program.

Comment: yes, but that's a function of the code you're running.  most, if not all, libraries that provide support for parallelising your code allow you to place limits on how many threads will be started.  depending on what you're running, and the lib you're using, the default may be to use as many cores as are available.

Comment: @cas - This behavior is happening outside of parallelized operations. If you are familiar with R, I can add an example that produces the behavior.

Comment: Vaguely familiar with it, in that I've done sysadmin and tech support for researchers running R-based jobs on HPC clusters and departmental servers and their desktop machines, but have never needed to use it for my own work.

Comment: You may want to look into cgroups.  I’ve got a couple questions/answers posted about them on this site.  Also, ulimits, and renice.  These are suggestions for areas to research, since I don’t know the best answer for your situation.

Comment: @Wildcard - cgroups does indeed seem to be a good possible solution here. Thanks for the suggestion - I will look into this further.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's going on here or what's the question or how to help, but y'all should start using `nice` to launch your batched processes.

The `nice` program allows a nice user to declare a job low priority, so e.g. it would give priority to other people's shells (unless for some reason they are "nicer"), in order to make everyone else's life easier.

Run `htop` and watch this:

Run this:

```
stress --cpu 4
```

Open another tab, run this:

```
nice -n 19 stress --cpu 4
```

You'll see the latter only works when there's CPU time available left from other batches not so nicer.

**Yes** I'd say you want Ismael to launch is huge batch with "high niceness".

If he wouldn't, you can run `htop` with super user privileges, if you can, and make his batch nicer even from the very `htop` program.